# How to set CONSISTENCY level in cassandra permanently?

Tags: cassandra, consistency

I want to set consistency level to QUORUM, I am able to do this using cqlsh with using 'CONSISTENCY QUORUM'. but the problem is that that was set to only for that particular time. I don't see any property related to CONSISTENCY level in cassandra.yaml.

Is there any way to set it permanently, any configuration file?

Answer (score 3):

There is no such properly in cassandra.yaml. But you can do it by appropriately setting the below line in bin/cqlsh.py

```
self.consistency_level = cassandra.ConsistencyLevel.QUORUM
```

Answer (score 2):

The consistency level is set per request so its up to the client (ie cqlsh or your driver in whatever language) to set. It cannot be done from Cassandra's side.

cqlsh does allow you to setup some options via its [cqlshrc](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/cqlshrc.html) file but setting the default consistency level is not one of them. The default is actually [hard coded to CL.ONE](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/aaf201128764cc27905837c1882800c5ae542769/bin/cqlsh.py#L537). If you really want you can just change that line in cqlsh.py and it will be applied globally like Arun recommended above.